# Restkit + Coredata - Add only unique objects into One-to-Many relationship

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, core-data, restkit, restkit-0.20

I have a node detail webservice which is something like this:

```
<nid>23</nid>
<timestamp>1345634</timestamp>
<name>Some Name</name>
<synonym_nids>
 <item>
  45
 </item>
 <item>
  85
 </item>
</synonym_nids>
```

I have created `RKManagedObjectMapping` with my `NSManagedObject` subclass which is supposed to maintain the above structure. The nid's mentioned above (both `<nid>` and `<synonym_nids>`) are unique. The synonym collection in itself should have unique nids.

I could mark `<nid>` as unique during mapping using the API `-setPrimaryKeyAttribute` to the main level xml mapping with the NSManagedObject subclass. I do check the value of timestamp in local object and compare it with the returned `<timestamp>` from a listing API and mark the object as 'dirty' only if the timestamp is outdated. I next fetch the detail of only those nodes whose 'dirty bit' is set - The above shown XML is an extract from detail API. Now, when the dirty bit is set and when the fetching of detail API is completed, I end up adding multiple synonym ids into the relationship set because there is no mechanism (as per my study till now) in Restkit to check if the nid's 45 and 85 (in this case) are already existing in the relationship set. So, naturally Restkit ends up adding multiple entries for nid 45 and 85 each time the object is marked as 'dirty'. Also since there is no inherent mechanism to directly enter `NSNumber` inside the `NSSet` (one to many) relationship using coredata, I have created a wrapper object around `NSNumber` which is a `NSManagedObject` subclass to add it into the relationship set.

The model object looks like this:

```
@interface NGArticle : NSModelBase <NGArticleObjectMappingProtocol>
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * nodeID; // <nid>
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * prominentCommonName; // <name>
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSDate * lastChanged; // <timestamp>
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet *lookAlike; // <synonym_nids>
@end

@interface NGArticle (CoreDataGeneratedAccessors)
-(void)addLookAlikeObject:(NGInteger64*)value;
-(void)removeLookAlikeObject:(NGInteger64*)value;
-(void)addLookAlike:(NSSet*)values;
-(void)removeLookAlike:(NSSet*)values;
@end
```

How do I efficiently handle this case? Is there any inherent capability in Restkit to handle such scenarios?

**Update:**

Structure of NGInteger64 object:

```
@interface NGInteger64:NGModelBase
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber *number; // This number is of Integer 64 type which is set in managed object model's xcdatamodel file.
@end
```

Please note that `NGModelBase` is a subclass of `NSManagedObject` and hence `NGArticle` and `NGInteger64` are subclasses of `NSManagedObject` too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Restkit ends up adding multiple entries for nid 45 and 85 each time

This means that you haven't taught RestKit how to find the existing instances of the entities for the specified identifier. In this case RestKit is creating new objects and adding them to the relationships.

> I could mark  as unique during mapping

Yes, you must do this to avoid duplicates. The name specified to `setPrimaryKeyAttribute` should be the attribute on the entity (not the source key in the XML), so `nodeID`.

Comment: Yes, I am avoiding duplicates at the node level by marking them as primary key using -setPrimaryKeyAttribute, but I am not sure how to avoid duplicate entries being added into the set 'lookAlike' using this, any leads you got for me?

Comment: What is NGInteger64, it needs a defined unique identifier too.

Comment: NGInteger64 is just a wrapper object around NSNumber because we cannot specify NSNumber as destination for a relationship in xcdatamodel file. It just has one NSNumber member variable. However, the NGInteger64 object which will have the references nid 45 and 85 in this case should not be added multiple times in the 'lookAlike' set.

Comment: Updated the question to add more details.

Comment: Did you set `number` as the unique identifier for `NGInteger64` in the mapping?

Comment: No, I didn't set number as unique identifier for NGInteger64 mapping. Doing so will avoid adding multiple entries of NGInteger64 objects with same number into the 'lookAlike' set?